# In Javascript, is there a way to force one event handler to wait for another to finish when they're both called?

Tags: javascript, promise, event-handling

I have two form elements on my HTML page: an `input` and a `select`.

Bound to the `input` is a `blur` event handler; bound to the `select` is a `change` event handler.

When you edit the `input` element and then click an option in the `select` element, both events are triggered.  As it stands, the `blur` event is called before the `change`, which is what I want.  I don't know if that's a happy coincidence, or if that's the way the spec is written.  This is how it's programmed in my code:

```
select.addEventListener("change", selFxn);
input.addEventListener("blur", blurFxn);
var a, b;

async blurFxn(e) {
    a = await fxn1(e);
    b = await fxn2(a)
    input.value = b;
}
async selFxn(e) {
    b = await fxn3(a);
    input.value = b
}
```

However, is there some way inherent in the event handlers to force the function attached to the `change` event to wait for the function attached to the `blur` event to finish before it is called?
**EDIT** Both functions modify the same global variable, but I can't have that variable modified by another function in the middle of a function call.

My current solution is to create a global promise that is created by `blur` and used by `change` to wait for the `blur` function to finish.  But I'd rather not have to add this (minor) complexity if I don't have to.

Comment: There's no point making event handlers `async` functions, as the browser runtime will not pay attention to the returned Promise objects.

Comment: @Pointy The functions are also used elsewhere in the code, where they need to be asynchronous.

Comment: OK, well that's fine, of course it's impossible for anybody to understand that as you did not describe or post code details for those functions.

Comment: There is nothing built into JavaScript that does what you want. So you would need to code it yourself. hard to help without seeing code.

Comment: @epascarello Not sure what I could add to the code that would help.  Variables are set and changed in the functions, other functions are called, etc.  But nothing that affects the event calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there some way inherent in the event handlers to force the function attached to the change event to wait for the function attached to the blur event to finish before it is called?

No.  There is no way for you to control the order these two events fire.  They fire in the order the system decides to fire them.  And, there are certainly circumstances where a `change` event fires with no associated `blur` event as the `blur` event occurs when the item loses focus and `change` events are possible without losing focus (and thus no `blur` event).

Similarly, you can get a `blur` event without an associated `change` event too.

If you want your processing of one to precede the other, then you'd have to implement some sort of system where you wait some short period of time (with a timer) to see if the two events are paired (if a 2nd associated event is immediately coming) and, if so, then process them in the order you want and if only one event arrived within that timer, then process the one event that you got.

If the two events are both associated with the same end-user action, then they will likely come sequentially with very little time between them so even a short 50ms timer would probably suffice to see if the 2nd event is coming or not and that short a delay would be unlikely to be noticed by the user.

If we understood better what you're trying to do in processing the two events, we could better advise on specific code to handle this situation.

It's also worth noting that if your event handlers are actually doing asynchronous things (which it seems like they probably are since you made them `async`), then there is also no way to make the 2nd event handler "wait" until the `async` function of the first event handler is completely done.  Once you return from the previous event handler, even if some asynchronous operation is not yet complete, then the 2nd event handler can fire.

Comment: Edit to my post: "Both functions modify the same global variable, but I can't have that variable modified by another function in the middle of a function call."

Comment: @DanielH - Please show the REAL and actual code.  Questions like this have no generic answer beyond what I've already provided.  A more specific answer needs to see your actual code and advise a specific way to code your specific problem.

Comment: @DanielH - And, probably the solution is to not have one global variable that multiple asynchronous things are fighting over.  It needs to be coded in a better way.

Comment: I've edited the code, but the generic answer is all I really need.

Comment: @DanielH - What you show is unstable code.  You have two asynchronous things attempting randomly timed usage of shared variables.  That's unpredictable and thus a race condition that will generate inconsistent results.

Comment: Thank you, and I do recognize the issues you're point out.  I'm trying to fix the code now.  I mainly needed to know if what I wanted was even possible.